# Struggling to iter over attributes in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-models

**Here is my code:**

```
class Product(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    descripition = models.TextField()
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    attributes = models.ManyToManyField('Attribute')

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    class Meta :
        ordering = ("-date",)

class ProductVariant(models.Model) :
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    for attri in product.attributes :
        attri.name = models.ForeignKey(AttributeVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'attribute.name': attri.name})

    class Meta :
        ordering = ("name",)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.product.name + self.name

class Attribute(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

    class Meta :
        ordering = ("name",)

class AttributeVariant(models.Model) :
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='values')

    class Meta :
        ordering = ("name",)

    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name
```

What I'm trying to do :

In the ProductVariant Class, I'm trying to iter through the product attributes and to assign to each of them a field ForeignKey to AttributeVariants to get the values of this specific attribute. It corresponds to the code below:

```
for attri in product.attributes :
    attri.name = models.ForeignKey(AttributeVariant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'attribute.name': attri.name})
```

However, when I try to run *python manage.py makemigrations*, I get

```
    for attri in product.attributes :
        AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'attributes'
```

Please let me know if you find the solution to this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: This is... not a thing you would do. I can't understand why you're trying to do it. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: inside this loop, `for attri in product.attributes`, are you aware that you will have multiple `ForeignKey`, this will end up with multiple `related_name` with same names, this will never work in Django as fas as I know